# Loading subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview named as `tvViewController` with nib.
Here is my .h file code

```
    @interface tvViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableview;
```

Here is my .m file code: I have synthesize the tableview too:

```
#import "tvViewController.h"

@interface tvViewController()
@implementation tvViewController
@synthesize myTableview;
```

I have another viewcontroller named as `"settingViewController"` where I need to resize(smaller) and load the `tvViewController` with all its functions.

For that I have written the code as below in the `settingViewController's` `viewdidload`. But it is not showing the nib of `tvViewController`. It is just showing a plain white color table which is not the `"tvViewController"`.

```
  tvViewController *vc1 = [[tvViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"tvViewController" bundle:nil];

 vc1.myTableview=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 250, 300) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

  [self addChildViewController:vc1];
  [self.view addSubview:vc1.myTableview];
```

if I commented the tableview `initWithFrame` code, then the white color plain table also not displaying. I think the way I called is incorrect, please help me to load it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your View Controller is not a subclass of UITableViewController, you need to set the tableview's delegate and datasource to self.

```
myTableView.delegate = self;
myTableView.dataSource = self;
```